# Doubt regarding Velocity-Time graph with Constant Accleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

[image: Porblem 7]

I think the answer is (A) initially. However, what about option (C)? It also shows a graph with constant acceleration and a negative slope. And in option (E), the acceleration is 0. Can we consider this as constant acceleration too? It's frustrating that the question maker didn't provide the answer in their paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initial velocity is not 0 in condition C and E.

Comment: Thanks i over looked the question